# Deploy spring boot war to weblogic 12.2.1 (versioning)

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jhipster, versioning, weblogic12c

I did the below :

1. Extend intilizer servlet from webintilizer
2. Make tomcat dependence as provided
3. Change packaging to war
4. Put weblogic.xml and servletdispatcher.xml as spring.io doc

Deployment steps :

1. Deploy first time without error
2. Update old deployment by apply versioing some times working and some times getting error parsing descriptor in web application

But after restart the manged server on weblogic the issue disappered

Note : My app has another spring boot app as dependency

Why ?

Comment: Why the `servletdispatcher.xml`? You don't need it. Nor should you have a `web.xml`.

Comment: You meant if I delete it the problem will solved without add web.xml?